# responsive max width does not working

Tags: html, css

i want to make responsive image slider but i change #wrapper ul width to max-width so responsive doesn't work.I do not know what to do.It does not work well.please help me for this problem.

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.after::after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
#main{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  background:yellow;
  margin-top:30px;
}
#wrapper{
  position:relative;
  max-width:800px;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#wrapper ul{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  max-width:3200px;/* it doesn't work*/
}
#wrapper ul li{
  width:800px;
  height:400px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="main" class="after">
    <div id="wrapper" class="after">
      <ul class="after">
        <li style="background:red;"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x400" /></li>
        <li style="background:green;"></li>
        <li style="background:blue;"></li>
        <li style="background:purple;"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's working but it's a max-width that you will neve reach ... probably you need to set `width` and not `max-width`

Comment: i set width instead of max-width but responsive doesn't work

Comment: "Not working" is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the max-width in your #wrapper to 800px. 
You've set the max-width of the #wrapper ul to 3200px.

I might be mistaken, but logically speaking the ul will only ever reach 800px because the max width of the wrapper that it is inside is set to 800px.

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper ul li {
    /* width: 800px; remove it  */
    height: 400px;
    /* float: left; remove it  */
}
```

And  add  `#wrapper ul li img { max-width : 100% }`

Everything will be responsive perfectly.

Full code

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.after::after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
#main{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  background:yellow;
  margin-top:30px;
}
#wrapper{
  position:relative;
  max-width:800px;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#wrapper ul{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  max-width:3200px;/* it doesn't work*/
}
#wrapper ul li{
  height:400px;
}
#wrapper ul li img { max-width : 100% }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="main" class="after">
    <div id="wrapper" class="after">
      <ul class="after">
        <li style="background:red;"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x400" /></li>
        <li style="background:green;"></li>
        <li style="background:blue;"></li>
        <li style="background:purple;"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```